# Launcher.LaunchUriAsync() using HTTPS in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, uri, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to launch URI that is "https", but not getting the result.
See my code below

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.abc.com/get");
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Does the website exist? Is there anything in the website logs?

Comment: @BenjaminDiele yes, I am able to open using google chrome or firefox. Thank you

Comment: Do you own the website? Can you test on a site on which you have access to the logs?

Comment: @BenjaminDiele I think I need SSL certificate, right?

Comment: Indeed. [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/?app=1) offers free certificates. But perhaps you could also find the issue by sniffing the network traffic and capturing the responses.

Comment: @BenjaminDiele I do not know about network traffic and all, how to deal with it? thanks!!

Comment: I haven't yet looked into WP specific network debugging, but a good general program is [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) if you are running the app on the emulator.